# How to implement pull to refresh for Flutter WebView

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I am having issue with implementing pull to refresh the flutter WebView. My application consist of single screen and present webpage. I am confused how to implement as I tried to use RefreshIndicator but it didn't worked.
here is my code

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size * 0.05,
    child: AppBar(
      //leading: Image.asset(gnTabIcon),
      elevation: 3.5,
      shadowColor: AppColors.navyBlue,
      backgroundColor: AppColors.orange,
      title: const Text(title),
      actions: <Widget>[
        NavigationControls(_controller.future), // control navigation
      ],
    ),
  ),


  // build scaffold for main app
  body: Builder(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Stack(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15.0),
            child: WebView(
              gestureNavigationEnabled: false,
              initialUrl: url,
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              zoomEnabled: false, // disable pinch to zoom

              onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) {
                print('WebView is created');
                _controller.complete(webViewController);
              },
              onProgress: (int progress) {
                print("WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)");
                splashScreenDelay(progress);
              },
              javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{
                _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
              },

              onPageStarted: (String url) {
                print('Page started loading: $url');
                _loadingStateTrue();
              },
              onPageFinished: (String url) {
                print('Page finished loading: $url');
                _loadingStateFalse();
              },
            ),
          ),
          isLoading
              ? Center(
                  child: GnLoader(),
                )
              : Stack(),
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
);
}
```

I have tried to search on internet but nothing worked fine as the approach is different and confusing as well. Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to call reload method of your WebviewController

Create Webview Controller

```
WebViewController _webViewController;
```

in your Webview

```
onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                _controller = webViewController;
},
```

then call `_controller.reload();` in Pull.
You can Use Pull_to_refresh Package

Comment: I tried to do it but got this error "Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      _GimmeNowWebState._onRefresh (package:gn_mobile_flutter_customer_mobile_web/views/gn_webview.dart:134:23)
<asynchronous suspension>"